# Python remove specific line ""

Tags: python, csv

I'am currently writing a python programm thats extracs phone Numbers into a file.

Since the Data quality is not that great yet we have a few blank numbers.
The file looks something like this:

```
xxxxx
1241515151
""
""
""
""
""
+43 2414141414
0221412414
""
01989797 8
214141
```

My Question is how do I remove the lines with "".

I tried:

```
f = open("fastlane.txt","r+")
d = f.readlines()
f.seek(0)
for i in d:
    if i != " ""$ ":
        f.write(i)
f.truncate()
f.close()
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `open( 'b.txt', 'w').write( '\n'.join( i.strip() for i in open('a.txt').readlines() if not i.startswith('"') )

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with regex

You can filter number and special chars containing `+` or `-` or space

```
import re
with open("fastlane.txt","r+") as f:
    re.findall(r'[\d +-]+', f.read())

# ['1241515151', '+43 2414141414', '0221412414', '01989797 8', '214141']
```

Or to filter everything except quotes and newline

```
re.findall(r'[^"\n]+', f.read())
# ['xxxxx', '1241515151', '+43 2414141414', '0221412414', '01989797 8', '214141']
```

Comment: does not work with numbers that include anything beyond digits and spaces, like '1-800-NEED-HELP` or even `1-800-6453-6323', as a reminder, the original question was "how to remove lines with double quotes?"....

Comment: @lenik. Thanks for the comment. I have updated the answer

Comment: @Sunitha thanks for the answers, sadly it does not seem like this is working for my case. I edited the file and added some double quotes myself. Those are getting removed just fine. The ones created in the regular txt stay.